# iTunes Connect Add Localization bug: "The App Name you entered has already been used."

Tags: localization, app-store-connect

I created a new App in iTunesConnect with German as the Defaut Language. When I tried to add another localization (**UPDATE**: trying to add it in iTunesConnect for the same App, where you modify the apps metadata) I got the error: "The App Name you entered has already been used.", but I didn't modify it, the App Name is the same as under German.

Has anyone else encountered this?

Are we requiered now to give a different Application Name for each localization?
Before, we had the same App Name for each localization.

If we can give different App Names for different localizations why can't we have the same App Name for each localization as before?

What's your experience?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think you've got the process wrong. You don't upload a different app for each language. You need to embed localisation in the app itself. See http://www.icanlocalize.com/site/tutorials/iphone-applications-localization-guide/

Comment: @ThomasClayson - Sorry I didn't express myself clearly enough. When I said "I tried to add another localization", I meant it in iTunes Connect, where you modify your App's metadata. So the App is the same of course, and that's why I don't understand why I can't add the English description with the same App Name.